# How to write readinessprobe for sidekiq

Tags: sidekiq, readinessprobe

Since sidekiq doesn't provide external URL, is there anyway to add readinessprobe to sidekiq container?
The container only runs

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

right now.
Can I write a simple script which just executes sidekiq command and how do I expose it to make is available in readiness probe?

Answer (score 1):

I researched the same problem and only found two solutions that were over-complicated and inefficient - both the [most popular solution](https://github.com/arturictus/sidekiq_alive) and [GitLab's](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/sidekiq/sidekiq_health_check.html) solution uses a webserver. I propose the following alternative which uses a file last modified timestamp:

A job using [`sidekiq-scheduler`](https://github.com/sidekiq-scheduler/sidekiq-scheduler) set to execute every 30s. The job does only one thing - touches a temporary file in the project directory.

***Note:** Make sure the job runs with maximum priority, and the configuration allows for a heartbeat to be missed. If there are other long-running high priority jobs, this might produce a false positive.*

`config/sidekiq.yml`

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command: [ bin/check_worker_health ]
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 30
  failureThreshold: 2
```

`app/jobs/worker_healthcheck_job.rb`

```rb
##
# Updates the last access time of tmp/worker_healthcheck so the health of the worker can
# be measured by: bin/check_worker_health
class WorkerHealthcheckJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :critical

  HEALTHCHECK_FILE = Rails.root.join( 'tmp/worker_healthcheck' ).to_s

  def perform
    `touch #{HEALTHCHECK_FILE}`
  end
end
```

The following is a script that would return a non-zero exit code if the file doesn't exist. After which removes the file to restart the check process:

`bin/check_worker_health`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

JOB_INTERVAL=30
HEALTHCHECK_FILE=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f "$0")))/tmp/worker_healthcheck

# Check if $HEALTHCHECK_FILE exists
if [ -f $HEALTHCHECK_FILE ]; then
  # Check if the file was created less than $JOB_INTERVAL seconds
  if [ "$(( $(date +"%s") - $(date -r $HEALTHCHECK_FILE +%s) ))" -gt "$JOB_INTERVAL" ]; then
    exit 2 # File created more than $JOB_INTERVAL seconds ago
  fi

  # Delete the file to prepare the next check
  rm $HEALTHCHECK_FILE
  exit 0
else
  exit 1 # File does not exist
fi
```

And just for posterity, here is a spec that makes sure it's all working correctly:

`spec/jobs/worker_healthcheck_job.rb`

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe WorkerHealthcheckJob, type: :job do

  describe '#perform' do
    it 'uses tmp/worker_healthcheck as its target file' do
      expect( described_class::HEALTHCHECK_FILE ).to eq Rails.root.join( 'tmp/worker_healthcheck' ).to_s
    end

    context 'when the healthcheck file does not exist' do
      before do
        delete_healthcheck_file
      end

      it 'the file to exist' do
        described_class.perform_now
        expect( Pathname.new( described_class::HEALTHCHECK_FILE ) ).to exist
      end
    end

    context 'when the healthcheck already exists' do
      before do
        create_stale_healthcheck_file
      end

      it 'the file to exist' do
        described_class.perform_now
        expect( File.mtime( described_class::HEALTHCHECK_FILE ) ).to be > 1.second.ago
      end
    end
  end

  describe '#perform_later' do
    it 'enqueues the job in the critical queue' do
      expect { described_class.perform_later }.to have_enqueued_job.on_queue( :critical )
    end
  end

  describe 'bin/check_worker_health' do
    context 'without a healthcheck file' do
      before do
        delete_healthcheck_file
      end

      it 'exits with code 1' do
        system( Rails.root.join( 'bin/check_worker_health' ).to_s )
        expect( $?.exitstatus ).to eq 1
      end
    end

    context 'with a stale healthcheck file' do
      before do
        create_stale_healthcheck_file
      end

      it 'exits with code 2' do
        system( Rails.root.join( 'bin/check_worker_health' ).to_s )
        expect( $?.exitstatus ).to eq 2
      end
    end

    context 'after the worker healthcheck job' do
      before do
        described_class.perform_now
      end

      it 'exits with code 0' do
        system( Rails.root.join( 'bin/check_worker_health' ).to_s )
        expect( $?.exitstatus ).to eq 0
      end
    end
  end

  def delete_healthcheck_file
    File.delete( described_class::HEALTHCHECK_FILE ) if File.exist?( described_class::HEALTHCHECK_FILE )
  end

  def create_stale_healthcheck_file
    `touch #{described_class::HEALTHCHECK_FILE} --date $(date -Is -d '1 hour ago')`
  end
end
```